# Which algorithm fits best to a transactional data classification problem?

Tags: classification, data-mining, dataset

I have transactional database - the data looks as follows:

> **ID - COLUMN1 - COLUMN2 - COLUMN3**
>
> 0 - **A** - B - C
>
> 0 - A - **D** - C
>
> 0 - E - B - **C**
>
> 1 - A - B - C
>
> 1 - A - B - C
>
> 2 - **A** - **D** - C
>
> 2 - A - B - **F**
>
> 3 - A - D - C
>
> 3 - **A** - **B** - **F**
>
> 3 - A - B - C

Now I want to use a classification algorithm to classify fraud:

> **ID - CLASSIFICATION**
>
> 0 - critical (because of the pattern "A D C")
>
> 1 - uncritical (no conspicuous pattern detected)
>
> 2 - critical (A D F)
>
> 3 - critical (A B F)

The patterns can occur on only one row or more rows. 1 Transaction contains multiple rows (-> ID).

Which algorithm fits best or which algorithms comes in question?

Comment: Are you simply trying to detect the three patterns you have outlined ? Then a rule based system would be sufficient.

Comment: The problem is, this patterns can occure some kind of "random". For example: in one Transaction the important values are in row 1 and 2. In the next transaction in row 2, 3 and 5.

Comment: Have you though about treating the columns for an ID as several sets and looking for the membership of the pattern within those sets ? Would that catch all the rules you want to identify ?

Comment: thanks an idea. You think that there isnt a algorithmn which fits to the data as it is?

Comment: Your identifying patterns seem to be spread over rows ... so you would want an algorithm that considered multiple rows, or you could join all rows for an ID together in to a variable length vector and then search for positional patterns.  From what you have presented you seem to be looking purely for patterns, a more general machine learning algorithm would  only perform at best the same and more likely worse than matching patterns by rules.

Comment: you could tackle this using regular expressions to implement the pattern detection, such as is available in awk, perl, python, java etc.